# Infiniti FX50 P0524 P0021

Tags: infiniti

I have a problem with my 09 FX50 V8. The engine control is on. I already read on this site, that this could be the oil pressure sensor.

P0524: It was written that two of them were changed to new ones, but I can only find one in my car.
Has anyone has experience with this error? Is it sufficient to change the sensor?

P0021: Is it ok to clean the cam valve sensor?

It is a lil bit strange, that both errors came together. In the 3.7 engine this would be a sign of a cracked galley gasket, which is very expensive to repair. But I read that it‘s not possible in the V8, bc there isn‘t such a gasket.

Answer (score 1):

just to give an update. The error p0021 was solved with changing the cam shaft solenoid on bank two (passenger side on the FX50!!), the upper one, not the lower. The oil pressure error didn‘t came back, as I filled the oil to the maximum. Hope I can help someone with this experience.

Answer (score 0):

With a P0524 you want to verify that it's a bad sensor or actually low oil pressure.  Continuing to drive with low oil pressure can quickly cause severe damage to your engine requiring extensive and expensive repairs.

You will need to directly measure the car's oil pressure with an external oil pressure gauge.  These are relatively inexpensive but finding and getting to the proper place to measure the pressure may be tricky and it's likely the same place that the potentially bad sensor mounts.  You may be better off taking it to a shop that can do this for you if you are not comfortable with this type of work.

P0021 could very well be a related code and it may be due to the ECU being confused about how much input the cam position actuator needs or may be due to an actual oil pressure issue.  I would address the P0524 issue first and see if this one clears up on its own.

As far as actually having low oil pressure I assume you have checked the most obvious potential problems:

1. Low oil level.
2. Clogged oil filter.
3. Improper oil type or viscosity.

Apart from this you may have a clogged oil pickup screen in the oil sump, you may have a clogged oil line, you may have a worn or damaged oil pump, you may have a cracked block or cylinder head, you may have a head or other gasket problem.

In all these cases we're talking about significant repairs.  Good luck!

If the pressure is normal, then you know you have a bad sensor.  Change it.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! 
I already ordered a new oil pressure sensor, that’s what I‘m starting with. At the same time, I‘ll try to detect the oil pressure. 

I already deleted the errors one time, but the yellow control light is on again. But not the red one for very low oil pressure, it was not switched until now.

Comment: Around here many auto parts stores rent common tools like oil pressure gauges.  They don't really "rent" them since you leave a deposit and get 100% of it back when you return the tool.